# Swift - Stopping an animation after the last image has appeared?

Tags: swift

I'm trying to learn animation in swift. I have an explosion composed of 77 images, and I've stumbled upon a couple issues.

1) I'm trying to make the animation automatically stop once 77.png has appeared. Here is what I have so far. Obviously, it is currently in a continuous animation loop.

2) There is ~1 second delay for the animation to start. However, after it has animated once, and I click animate again, it is instant from then on. How can I make the first animation instant as well?

```
@IBOutlet var explosionSequence: UIImageView

var imgListArray :NSMutableArray = []

for countValue in 1...77 {
    var strImageName : String = "\(countValue).png"
    var image  = UIImage(named:strImageName)
    imgListArray .addObject(image)
}

explosionSequence.animationImages = imgListArray as [AnyObject];
explosionSequence.startAnimating()

//i want to stop animation here after all 77 .pngs have appeared
```

thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 6):

You can use UIImageView method [animationRepeatCount](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImageView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIImageView/animationRepeatCount) to limit your animation loop to 1.

> The default value is 0, which specifies to repeat the animation
>   indefinitely:

```
explosionSequence.animationRepeatCount = 1
```

You can also use [animationDuration](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImageView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIImageView/animationDuration) to adjust the time of you animation.